# How to prevent charger cables wearing out too quickly?

Tags: technology, phone

All of my phone charging leads have frayed at the ends where you plug it in. I've spent a lot on getting these braided cords that are supposed to last for a while but they never last. I have in total about 20 broken cords.

How do I make my cords last longer?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the common trick of wrapping a spring from a pen around either end of your cable.

http://www.padandquill.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/iphone-charger-pen-spring-fix.jpg[image]

As your cable flexes and bends during use, the springs will help relieve the tension being placed on them and over time will slow down the damage you're experiencing.

Here is a good guide on how to do it:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Protectect-your-iPhone-iPod-sync-cable/

And a how-to video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VCIo8xGTUX0

I've also used Tetsujin's suggestion in the past and it is a good solution if you have some Sugru handy.

Answer (score 1):

[**Sugru**](https://sugru.com/blog/14-apple-life-hacks) - not cheap, but very good.

Goes on like Plasticene/Silly Putty, dries like rubberised plastic. Flexible & waterproof, lots of different colours.

[image]

[image]